# Extreme Value theorem for normed space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

We know that for a real-valued function, a  continuous mapping A to R from a compact subset of A to R, the function achieves its maximum and minimum value. One reason for this is that compactness is preserved and the sup and inf are limit points that belong to the closed set.

Now I was wondering is there a more generalized version of the extreme value theorem for mapping from one normed space to another assuming the norm is induced by a metric. If we have a continuous mapping from a compact subset of $R^m$ to $R^n$, can we still say the mapping achieves a maximum or minimum in the sense that the norm is maximized or minimized? If not, is there anything we can say

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be a compact subspace of any topological space and let $V$ be any normed vector space. If $f : C \to V$ is a continuous mapping, then the mapping $g : C \to \Bbb{R}$, such that $g(x) =  \|f(x)\|$ is the composite of the continuous mappings $f: C \to V$ and $v \mapsto \|v\| : V \to \Bbb{R}$ and hence is continuous. So as $C$ is compact, $g : C \to \Bbb{R}$ is bounded and achieves its maximum and minimum, implying that $f$ achieves its maximum and minimum in the sense you describe.